# Visual Studio context menu/toolbar Set StartUp Projects

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am hoping to put a toolbar button (or configure a keyboard shortcut) for the Set StartUp Projects... solution context menu item.

If the solution is selected in Solution Explorer the Project menu has solution context items, but I cannot seem to find this command anywhere. I can only find single Set as StartUp Project and similar.

Does anyone know if I can do this?

EDIT: I found this extension which allows me to do what I want quite easily (define different combinations of start up projects): https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f4e1be8c-b2dd-4dec-b273-dd88f8818571

Comment: Please make your edit into an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: @mm201 sure, done. make sure you get the version for your edition of VS. I can vouch up until 2017 - I stopped using VS a few years ago :)

Comment: I just installed the 2019 version, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-141975.SwitchStartupProject) does exactly what I required. It has linked versions for other editions of VS. It uses json config files to start multiple projects nicely.

Answer (score 1):

It is the one command **Project.SetasStartUpProject** that works differently depending on whether a project or the solution is selected in Solution Explorer. To select the solution and then call **Project.SetasStartUpProject** you can probably use [Visual Commander](http://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) or [Macros for Visual Studio 2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d3fbf133-e51b-41a2-b86f-9560a96ff62b).

Comment: Ah, okay. I will have a look when I get to work tomorrow and see what I can knock up. Thanks for the clarification.